# Represent a subquery in relational algebra

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

How do I represent a subquery in relation algebra? Do I put the new select under the previous select condition?

```
SELECT number
FROM collection
WHERE number = (SELECT anotherNumber FROM anotherStack);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would just rewrite that as a `join`.

I'm not sure how widely used the syntax I learned for Relational Algebra is so in words.

1. Take a projection of `anotherNumber` from `anotherStack`
2. Rename `anotherNumber` from the result of step 1 as `number`
3. Natural Join the result of step 2 onto `collection`
4. Take a final projection of `number` from the result of step 3

Comment: One *could* rewrite that as a join :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on which operators your algebra comprises. A semi-join operator would be most useful here.

If the common attribute was named `number` in both relations then it would be a semi-join followed by projection of `number`. Assuming a sem-join operator named `MATCHING`, as per [Tutorial D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28data_language_specification%29):

```
( collection MATCHING anotherStack ) { number }
```

As posted, the attribute needs to be renamed first:

```
( collection MATCHING ( anotherStack RENAME { anotherNumber AS number } ) { number }
```

If Standard SQL's (SQL-92) `JOIN` can be considered, loosely speaking, a relational operator then it is true that SQL has no no semi-join. However, it has several comparison predicates that may be used to write a semi-join operator e.g. `MATCH`:

```
SELECT number
  FROM collection
 WHERE MATCH (
              SELECT * 
                FROM collection
               WHERE collection.number = anotherNumber.anotherStack
             );
```

However, `MATCH` is not widely supported in real life SQL products, hence why a semi-join is commonly written using `IN (subquery)` or `EXISTS (subquery)` (and I suspect that's why you name-checked "subquery" in your question i.e. the term semi-join is not well known among SQL practitioners).

---

Another approach would be to use an intersect operator if available.

Something like (pseudocode):

```
( collection project number ) 
intersect 
( ( anotherStack rename anotherNumber as number ) project number )
```

In SQL:

```
SELECT number
  FROM collection
INTERSECT
SELECT anotherNumber
  FROM anotherStack;
```

This is quite well supported in real life (SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc but notably not MySQL).

Comment: You should be a bit more precise in your choice of words.  If MATCH can be used in a WHERE clause (in the way you described), then that operator must return a boolean, and then MATCH cannot possibly be "a SEMIJOIN operator", as you claim.  A SEMIJOIN operator returns a relation.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://cs.ulb.ac.be/public/_media/teaching/infoh417/sql2alg_eng.pdf) pdf, you can convert a sub-query easily to a relational algebric expression.

Firstly, you have to convert the whole query from the form

```
SELECT Select-list FROM R1 T1, R2 T2, ...
WHERE
some-column = (
    SELECT some-column-from-sub-query from r1 t1, r2 t2, ...
    WHERE extra-where-clause-if-needed)
```

to

```
SELECT Select-list FROM R1 T1, R2 T2, ...
WHERE
EXISTS (
    SELECT some-column-from-sub-query from r1 t1, r2 t2, ...
    WHERE extra-where-clause-if-needed and some-column = some-column-from-sub-query)
```

Then you have to convert the sub-query first into relational algebra. To do this for the sub-query given above:

```
PI[some-column-from-sub-query](
    SIGMA[extra-where-clause-if-needed 
        ^ some-column = some-column-from-sub-query
        ](RO[T1](R1) x RO[T2](R2) x ... x RO[t1](r1) x RO[t2](r2) x ...)
)
```

Here `R1, R2...` are the contextual relations, and `r1, r2...` are sub-query relations.

As the syntax is pretty disaster in stack overflow, please head over to [that](https://cs.ulb.ac.be/public/_media/teaching/infoh417/sql2alg_eng.pdf) pdf to get a broad overview of how to convert sub query to relational algebra.