# Relational algebra equivalent of SQL "in"

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

What would be the equivalent relational algebra of the expression IN from SQL?
I'm trying to translate this SQL query:

```
SELECT rol, nota FROM notas WHERE rol IN ( SELECT rol FROM estudiantes WHERE ID = 1)
```

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Represent a subquery in relational algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850816/represent-a-subquery-in-relational-algebra)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the inner subquery as below

```
SELECT rol FROM estudiantes WHERE ID = 1
```

Equivalent Relational Algebra would be as below

```
∏rol(σ ID = 1 (estudiantes))
```

`σ ID = 1 (estudiantes)` will select all rows with condition `ID = 1` out of which you are projecting a subset of column namely `rol`.

**EDIT:**

If you want to simulate `IN` operator then you can go for `equi Join` on 
both your `notas` and `estudiantes` table on column named `rol`.

```
SELECT rol, nota FROM notas WHERE rol IN 
( 
SELECT rol FROM estudiantes WHERE ID = 1
)
```

Point to note: Explicitly qualify the `rol` column since both relation has the same name.

```
nota (equi join) estudiantes = 

project notas.rol,nota
(notas equijoin notas.rol = estudiantes.rol select ID = 1(estudiantes))
```

PS: Somehow, I am not able to print the symbols like (project,select,equi join etc). So ended up writing them as text.

Comment: That translates the example but does not answer the question, translating IN.

Comment: @philipxy, I almost got it but bit confused from the question. that can be done too with a `theta join`. on way ...

Comment: @philipxy, see edit. Hope this makes sense now. give +1 if it does :).

Comment: I would expect something in terms of an arbitrary IN use. Eg for A1,... attributes of R: SELECT ... FROM R WHERE (A1,...) IN S == ∏ ... (R EQUIJOIN S). (...I guess you are trying to say that.)

Comment: @philipxy, NO, there is no equivalent (AFAIK) `IN` in RA. So to simulate IN you can do a equi join/natural join and to simulate NOTIN you can do a `MINUS along with cartesian product`. Hope this make sense.

Comment: I just *gave* the mapping for the given case. I meant that your writing is not clear. Compare to my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use join to do this. I am using natural join for simplicity.

```
SELECT rol, nota FROM notas WHERE rol IN ( SELECT rol FROM estudiantes WHERE ID = 1)
```

This can be represented as following SQL using join. Once you change to this form, it is easy to represent in relational algebra.

```
SELECT rol, nota FROM (SELECT * from notas NATURAL JOIN estudiantes where ID=1)
```

It can be represented in relational algebra by

```
π rol, nota ((σ ID = 1 (estudiantes)) ⋈  notas)
```

I apologize that I could not use subscripts where required.

**Process**

Lets assume the relations contain following attributes
    notas(rol, nota, nota2, nota3, ...)
    estudiantes(id, rol, estudiantes1, estudiantes2, ...)

1) Change sub query to relational algebra. We can project `rol`, but it is not necessary, since natural join can be used without projecting.

```
SELECT rol FROM estudiantes WHERE ID = 1
π rol σ ID=1(estudiantes)
```

2) Natural join newly generated relation (in step 1) with notas. If the attribute names are different, you can use any other join

```
(π rol σ ID=1(estudiantes)) ⋈ notas
```

Since both relations contain attribute with same name `rol`, it will generate a relation like following:

```
(id, rol, nota, notas2, notas3, estudiantes1, estudiantes2, ...)
```

Relation `notas` is joined with the relation in 1, which only contain tuples with `id=1`. The resultant relation has all attributes of both, common attribute `rol` and `id` with value `1`.

3) The resulting relation contains all the values from both tables, so you can simply project required attributes

```
π rol, nota ( relation containing all values with id=1)
```

Hence we get the following relational algebra.

```
π rol, nota ((σ ID = 1 (estudiantes)) ⋈  notas)
```

Hope that helps.